# Inner Hits Aggregation Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've searched but can't quite find the answer. I'm using ElasticSearch but the aggregation counts are wrong for a nested aggregation. Below is my mappings and my query

MAPPING

```
{
      "mappings": {
         "providers_courses": {
            "properties": {
               "course_id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "course_name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "course_sessions": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "end_date": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                     },
                     "method": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "places_remaining": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "price": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "start_date": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "total_places": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "venue_address1": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "venue_address2": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "venue_building": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "venue_city": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "venue_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "venue_postcode": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "disciplines": {
                  "properties": {
                     "disciplines": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "include_in_parent": true
                     },
                     "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "provider_id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "provider_name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "sectors": {
                  "properties": {
                     "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "sectors": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "include_in_parent": true
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

QUERY

```
      {
       "size":1000,
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "must":[
                {
                   "match":{
                      "course_name":"safety"
                   }
                },
                {
                   "nested":{
                      "path":"course_sessions",
                      "inner_hits":{
                         "_source":[

                         ]
                      },
                      "query":{
                         "filtered":{
                            "query":{
                               "match_all":[

                               ]
                            },
                            "filter":{
                               "geo_distance":{
                                  "distance":"30miles",
                                  "course_sessions.location":{
                                     "lat":14.3263228,
                                     "lon":-1.8304209
                                  }
                               }
                            }
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       "aggs":{
          "sectors":{
             "filter":{
                "match_all":[

                ]
             },
             "aggs":{
                "sectors":{
                   "terms":{
                      "field":"sectors.raw"
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          "disciplines":{
             "filter":{
                "match_all":[

                ]
             },
             "aggs":{
                "disciplines":{
                   "terms":{
                      "field":"disciplines.raw"
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          "course_type":{
             "nested":{
                "path":"course_sessions"
             },
             "aggs":{
                "course_type":{
                   "terms":{
                      "field":"course_sessions.method"
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
}
```

RESULTS

The counts for the parent elements are fine but not for the nested object - I know that ultimately the query/filter needs to be applied to the aggregation but no matter how i try it doesnt work.

```
"aggregations": {
      "sectors": {
         "doc_count": 10,
         "sectors": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "3:Utilities",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "5:Health, Safety & Environment",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "6:Supervision, Leadership & Management",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "2:Offshore & Maritime",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "course_type": {
         "doc_count": 44,
         "course_type": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "Classroom",
                  "doc_count": 44
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "disciplines": {
         "doc_count": 10,
         "disciplines": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "3:Instrumentation",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "6:Production",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "7:Rigging & Lifting",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "8:Welding",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "1:Electrical",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "2:Engineering",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.